# Get string from @Test annotation TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to get a string from a TestNG annotation `@Test(groups="Foo")` and then use this as a name for a folder I am dynamically generating.

How do I get the text `"Foo"` from the TestNG annotation so I can use it?

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler solution to reading the attribute of the annotation (which would involve reflection and friends) would be to use the same constant String:

```
private static final String FOLDER = "Foo";

@Test(groups = FOLDER)
public void test() {
    //create the folder named FOLDER
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the annotation from a `Method` (which you can get from the `Class.get{,Declared}Methods()` method):

```
Test test = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
```

This will be non-null if the annotation was present, and null if it was not. If it is non-null, you can then just call the `groups()` method on `test`:

```
String groups = test.groups();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a `@BeforeMethod` method?

```
@BeforeMethod
public void generateFolderFromGroups(Method m) {
    Test test = m.getAnnotation(Test.class);
    String[] groups = test.groups();
    // generate folder from groups
}

@Test(groups = "Foo")
public void test() {
    // the Foo folder will be already created
}
```